# Functional programming incrementing integer sequence on every third one in C++1z?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17

I can write a C++ program to produce this output with for loops:

```
(200, 150)
(199, 150)
(198, 150)
(197, 149)
(196, 149)
(195, 149)
(194, 148)
(193, 148)
(192, 148)
(191, 147)
```

Using functional programming techniques (specifically with [C++ Streams](http://jscheiny.github.io/Streams/) a C++14 library) I am able to get to here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../Streams-master/source/Stream.h"
using namespace stream;
using namespace stream::op;
int main(){
    MakeStream::counter(200,-1)
        | zip_with(MakeStream::counter(150,-1))
        | limit(10)
        | for_each([](std::tuple<int, int>&& tup) {
            std::cout << tup << std::endl;
            });
    }
```

Produces:

```
(200, 150)
(199, 149)
(198, 148)
(197, 147)
(196, 146)
(195, 145)
(194, 144)
(193, 143)
(192, 142)
(191, 141)
```

What would a functional programming technique be for incrementing the second column on every third one, in C++1z?

Comment: What makes you believe that C++17 will add anything that will change the answer significantly from current C++?

Comment: @KerrekSB just not limiting to currently approved standard.

Comment: Using Eric Niebler's ranges-v3 (which should be standardized eventually), it looks like you could start with the second `counter` list, `view::transform` it with `view::repeat_n` to get a range of triplet ranges, then use `view::join` to flatten them, then zip that with the first `counter` list. Unfortunately, this idea is untested, so I'm probably missing something in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know C++, but maybe sketching a solution in Haskell will help?  You can write lists of decreasing integers this way in Haskell:

```hs
list1, list2 :: [Integer]
list1 = [200, 199..]
list2 = [150, 149..]
```

The first of these lists evaluates to the first elements of the pairs you're building.  For example, using the `take` function to extract the first 15 elements:

```hs
>> take 15 list1
[200,199,198,197,196,195,194,193,192,191,190,189,188,187,186]
```

The second, however, doesn't have the "skip" you want:

```hs
>> take 15 list2
[150,149,148,147,146,145,144,143,142,141,140,139,138,137,136]
```

However, we can build on that list to get one step closer:

```hs
list3 :: [Integer]
list3 = concatMap triplicate list2
    where triplicate n = [n, n, n]
```

Or using the `replicate` function from the standard library:

```hs
list4 :: [Integer]
list4 = concatMap (\n -> replicate 3 n) list2
```

This `concatMap`/`replicate` step seems to be what you're missing.  Example output:

```hs
>>> take 15 list4
[150,150,150,149,149,149,148,148,148,147,147,147,146,146,146]
```

Now, putting it all together with the `zip` function:

```hs
solution :: [Integer]
solution = zip [200, 199..] (concatMap (\n -> replicate 3 n) [150, 149..])
```

Example of using this:

```hs
>>> mapM_ print (take 10 solution) 
(200,150)
(199,150)
(198,150)
(197,149)
(196,149)
(195,149)
(194,148)
(193,148)
(192,148)
(191,147)
```

Note that the C++ Streams API has most if not all of the operations in this Haskell code (modulo small differences of detail), so the solution should translate fairly well:

1. Haskell `concatMap` = C++ `flat_map`
2. Haskell `replicate` = C++ `repeat`

Answer (score 0):

Per [Luis Casillas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094403/luis-casillas) Haskel answer and notes, add `| flat_map([](int x){return MakeStream::repeat(x,3);}))` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../Streams-master/source/Stream.h"
using namespace stream;
using namespace stream::op;
int main(){
    MakeStream::counter(200,-1)
    | zip_with(MakeStream::counter(150,-1)
        | flat_map([](int x){return MakeStream::repeat(x,3);}))
    | limit(10)
    | for_each([](auto tup) {std::cout << tup << std::endl;});
    }
```